# Is there an Android JAD-type file that can pass parameters to the APK?

Tags: android, apk, jad

In J2ME midlet development, you can pass runtime parameters to the midlet through a JAD file. Is there anything like this with Android? What I want is to pass basic custom information to the APK Activity when a user downloads it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no accompanying files like that.  What you can do is provide the information needed in Resources. There are [String](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), [Integer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer), [boolean](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool), and array resource data types available to you.  In addition you can add Extras to intents you send to your app or other apps.

Comment: Thanks. So when you deploy an APK - that's it - no customizing it?

Comment: Pretty much yes, there is no "external" customization such as provided by the .jad file but there are numerous options for "internal" customization. What ever you want to do the app will have to figure out on its own or with user input.

Comment: Cheers Dan. There's probably a way through editing the binary but it's too messy I reckon.

Comment: Almost forgot but there is also the assets directory where you can put any file in there. Much easier to include a flat file DB or binary data or anything you'd rather open as a file rather than a Resource.